# can't get psutil .net_connections() work the same in container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, microservices, psutil

Trying to create an containerized python app that collect host's process network data,

I've been using psutil to get the data,
when using `psutil.net_connection(kind='inet')`
Inside the docker container the PID value is always None,

I have used `--pid=host` and `--network=host` in the docker run command,

When I run the app out of a container it works but when trying it in the container it fails because of the None value,

Would love ideas